# Error while using .cache file with vowpal wabbit

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I am trying the examples given on vowpal-wabbit [tutorial](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Tutorial) but I am getting an error while using *.cache file for training. Error: 6 is too many tokens for a simple label: 8.3.0c�?�p�k>���>���L=��O�?@
                                                                                second_house�p�Q8>�ޙ�>�33�>��O�??
                                                                                                                 third_house�p�?��

```
V$ cat house_dataset
0 | price:.23 sqft:.25 age:.05 2006
1 2 'second_house | price:.18 sqft:.15 age:.35 1976
0 1 0.5 'third_house | price:.53 sqft:.32 age:.87 1924

V$ ls -lrth
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 A users 144 May  3 06:28 house_dataset
V$ vw --version
8.3.0
V$ vw house_dataset -c
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
creating cache_file = house_dataset.cache
Reading datafile = house_dataset
num sources = 1
average  since         example        example  current  current  current
loss     last          counter         weight    label  predict features
0.000000 0.000000            1            1.0   0.0000   0.0000        5
0.666667 1.000000            2            3.0   1.0000   0.0000        5

finished run
number of examples per pass = 4
passes used = 1
weighted example sum = 5.000000
weighted label sum = 2.000000
average loss = 0.600000
best constant = 0.500000
best constant's loss = 0.250000
total feature number = 16
V$ vw house_dataset.cache
Num weight bits = 18
learning rate = 0.5
initial_t = 0
power_t = 0.5
using no cache
Reading datafile = house_dataset.cache
num sources = 1
average  since         example        example  current  current  current
loss     last          counter         weight    label  predict features
Error: 6 is too many tokens for a simple label: 8.3.0c�?�p�k>���>���L=��O�?@
                                                                            second_house�p�Q8>�ޙ�>�33�>��O�??
                                                                                                             third_house�p�?��
0.000000 0.000000            1            1.0  unknown   0.0000        1
0.000000 0.000000            2            2.0  unknown   0.0000        1

finished run
number of examples per pass = 2
passes used = 1
weighted example sum = 2.000000
weighted label sum = 0.000000
average loss = 0.000000
total feature number = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

`$ vw --cache_file house_dataset.cache`

You can check command line arguments description [here](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-line-arguments).